# Error Trapping code using ADO connections

Tags: sql, vba

As a standard practice, I think most know that an ADO connection and recordset needs to be closed after you've gotten what you need from it.  I hadn't really thought to much about it in the past but I just became curious.  What is the proper method of error trapping when your using ADO to connect to the database?  I ask because if you produce an error while the connection is still open, using standard error trapping methods, the connection wouldn't get closed.  I would imagine this would cause memory issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Using standard error trapping methods, the connection wouldn't get closed.*

Depends how you implement it. I usually do something like this:

```vb
Public Sub DoSomething()
    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open

    ' do stuff

CleanExit:
    If Not conn Is Nothing Then conn.Close
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    ' handle errors - rollback transaction, etc.
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

I'd call it "standard error trapping", and it has yet to fail me.

---

There *are* other ways though. `ADODB.Connection` has a pretty rich API that's quite seldom used. You could wrap it up in a class module and encapsulate it in a `WithEvents` field, like this:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents MyConnection As ADODB.Connection
Private Const MyConnectionString As String = ""

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set MyConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    MyConnection.ConnectionString = MyConnectionString
    MyConnection.Open
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    If MyConnection Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    MyConnection.Close
    Set MyConnection = Nothing
End Sub

' public members...

Private Sub MyConnection_BeginTransComplete(ByVal TransactionLevel As Long, ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, ByVal pConnection As ADODB.Connection)
    Debug.Print "BeginTransComplete"
End Sub

Private Sub MyConnection_CommitTransComplete(ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, ByVal pConnection As ADODB.Connection)
    Debug.Print "CommitTransComplete"
End Sub

Private Sub MyConnection_ConnectComplete(ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, ByVal pConnection As ADODB.Connection)
    Debug.Print "ConnectComplete"
End Sub

Private Sub MyConnection_Disconnect(adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, ByVal pConnection As ADODB.Connection)
    Debug.Print "Disconnect"
End Sub

Private Sub MyConnection_ExecuteComplete(ByVal RecordsAffected As Long, ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, ByVal pCommand As ADODB.Command, ByVal pRecordset As ADODB.Recordset, ByVal pConnection As ADODB.Connection)
    Debug.Print "ExecuteComplete"
End Sub

Private Sub MyConnection_InfoMessage(ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, ByVal pConnection As ADODB.Connection)
    Debug.Print "InfoMessage"
End Sub

Private Sub MyConnection_RollbackTransComplete(ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, ByVal pConnection As ADODB.Connection)
    Debug.Print "RollbackTransComplete"
End Sub

Private Sub MyConnection_WillConnect(ConnectionString As String, UserID As String, Password As String, Options As Long, adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, ByVal pConnection As ADODB.Connection)
    Debug.Print "WillConnect"
End Sub

Private Sub MyConnection_WillExecute(Source As String, CursorType As ADODB.CursorTypeEnum, LockType As ADODB.LockTypeEnum, Options As Long, adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, ByVal pCommand As ADODB.Command, ByVal pRecordset As ADODB.Recordset, ByVal pConnection As ADODB.Connection)
    Debug.Print "WillExecute"
End Sub
```

I'd think if there's an error at any point, the `pError` parameter will include all the details about it:

[image: Object Browser showing members of ADODB.Error class]

Say that class module is named `DbConnection`, then you could use it like this:

```vb
Public Sub DoSomething()
    With New DbConnection
        'do stuff
    End With
End Sub
```

And whenever the object goes out of scope (whether `End With` was hit, or execution jumped out of the `With` block for whatever the reason), the `Class_Terminate` handler should run and ensure the encapsulated connection gets closed.

Comment: It makes sense to do it that way, but it would get very messy if you have several nested recordsets.

Comment: @Addohm if you have nested recordsets, then your code can probably be simplified to make a single query. I've never seen nested recordsets that weren't a mess.

Comment: @Addohm you might want to take a look at and adapt [Materializing any ADODB query](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/46506/23788) and [Creating ADODB parameters on the fly](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/46312/23788) on Code Review for your purposes - it simplifies ADO code quite much. Hope it helps!

Comment: I'll check those out, thanks!  I've thought about ways to ease the coding burden of ADODB queries but I just don't have to do it very often on the scale that I do now, on this project.

Comment: I see you wrote that.  Do you have some form of VBA code file (excel?) that shows the baseline structure and layout of what you wrote?

Comment: I will certainly check it out.  Right now I'm actually using a proprietary VBA IDE so I'm not sure it'll work well for this project, but I certainly have others I can play with it on!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133927/discussion-between-mats-mug-and-addohm).

Comment: I used your first example and it created a trap loop!  Froze the hell up out of the VBA IDE :D  For whatever reason it does not like evaluating rst or conn for content.

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to - feel free to make it a new question =)