# Excel vba SQL Stored procedure calling with input parameters

Tags: vba, excel, stored-procedures, input-parameters

Thank you in advance. I am trying to run a stored procedure from excel which accepts input parameters and it is giving error Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)' automation error.

```vb
   Set cmd1 = New ADODB.Command
             With cmd1
             .ActiveConnection = sConnString
             .CommandText = "spGetPriceChangeTest"
             .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
             .CommandTimeout = 360
             .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@suppliercode", adVariant, adParamInput, , Range("A" & (x + 2)).Value)
             .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@date1", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, , datetime)
             .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@proddescription", adVariant, adParamInput, , Range("D" & (x + 1)).Value)
             .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@vendorcode", adVariant, adParamInput, , Range("C" & (x + 2)).Value)
             .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@type", adVariant, adParamInput, , Range("B" & (x + 2)).Value)
             End With
             Set rst1 = New ADODB.Recordset
             Set rst1 = cmd1.Execute
```

Comment: You're `Set`-ing the exact same object reference twice: `Set rst1 = New ADODB.Recordset` is redundant and can be removed.

Comment: Is there not an actual opened connection somewhere? Which specific line is throwing the error?

Comment: removed it. Same error.

Comment: I know, I was just saying it's redundant. Do you have an `ADODB.Connection` object that you `.Open` anywhere? I've never used a `ADODB.Recordset` without an explicit `ADODB.Connection`... also try removing the `@` from the parameter names, and make sure the parameters are supplied in the exact same order as the SP is expecting them.

Comment: I have a connection object created and the command object executes with the help of the connection. Error is on the cmd1.execute statement. the connection is open and is working well as I have another stored procedures without parameters which are working well.

Comment: removed '@' and still got the same error.

Comment: The order is the same

Comment: try `Set .ActiveConnection = yourConnectionObject`, and if that still doesn't work then have this code written in a class module (a worksheet's code-behind can do), declare the connection `WithEvents` and handle its "on error" (not sure of the name) event to output the actual error message.

Comment: A quick Google search with "ADODB -2147217900 (80040e14)" seems to point to a syntax error. Verify the stored procedure works.

Comment: stored procedure works on dry run. tried passing the values by copying from the quick watch feature and it did run well in sql

Comment: datetime = DateSerial(2018, 2, 5) + TimeSerial(18, 0, 0) is one of the parameters to the sp. Can this be a problem ? the datatype for all the parameters in sql is varchar expect one which is datetime. can datatype on excel side be a problem?

Comment: well `adVariant` isn't `adVarChar`, for one

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41837692/1188513) for how you can listen to the messages your connection is sending. The event you want to handle is `InfoMessage`.

Comment: on changing it to adVarChar, it gives me run-time error 3708 application defined or object defined error.

Comment: Great! Progress! You need to handle the connection's `InfoMessage` event if you want to retrieve an actually helpful error message.

Comment: tell me how to do it. I am very new to vba. Any leads?

Comment: I just gave you a link, "see [this post]"...

Comment: Can you show me with an example. Please help. Can you show me with my code?

Comment: You're going to have to try a bit harder than that... SO is Q&A, not "hold my hand until it works" ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a parameter, ensure that the size defined in SQL is mentioned in the .CreateParameter("",adVarchar,***10***,value)

This post helped. It talks about how we can capture an error in detail.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/167957/info-extracting-error-information-from-ado-in-vb

Answer (score 0):

Try using `EXEC`:

```vb
.CommandText = "exec spGetPriceChangeTest"
```

Comment: Given `.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc`, I doubt this would be it. Changing `.CommandType` to `adCmdText` as well, could work though.

Comment: I have another stored procedures not accepting any parameters and it works as the code above perfectly. Im sensing that the datatype or the datetime parameter is an issue.